# How to run the Defn generated by the scalameta

Tags: scala, scalameta

I am playing with Scalameta. this is my build.sbt

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
   scalaVersion := "2.12.3"
)
lazy val macroProject = (project in file("MacroProject")).settings(
   commonSettings,
   name := "MacroProject",
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.scalameta" % "scalameta_2.12" % "2.0.1")
)

lazy val myProject = (project in file(".")).settings(
   commonSettings,
   name := "MyProject"
).dependsOn(macroProject)

mainClass in run := Some("com.abhi.HelloWorld")
```

In my MacroProject. I have the following code

```
import scala.meta._
import org.scalameta.logger

object MyMacros {
   def foo(a: Any, b: String) = {
      val result = q"def foo() : b = a.asInstanceOf[b]"
      result
   }
}
```

And now in my main Project I write

```
import com.abhi.MyMacros
MyMacros.foo("1", "Int").apply()
```

My hope was that I will be able to execute the method which was generated by my macro.

Edit: I also tried

```
object MyMacros {
   def foo(a: Any, b: String) = {
      val typeB = b.parse[Type]
      typeB match {
         case Success(t) => q"def foo() : $t = a.asInstanceOf[$t]"
         case _ => q"def foo() = Unit"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Add explicit return type to `foo`

Comment: OK I added return type... but I still am not able to call the method.

Comment: I don't see the return type there

Comment: I have been trying to understand scala.meta for some time, and the following reference was very helpful: [Metaprogramming magic with Scalameta](https://medium.com/@Arhelmus/metaprogramming-magic-with-scalameta-67e849ab490e)